# How to fix error in building the lidar_localizer package?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings,

I am unsure how to resolve the error in building autoware and i have been following the instructions on [this site](https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.ai/autoware/wikis/Source-Build).

system specs:

Ubuntu 16.04/
CUDA 9.0/
Eigen3/
Kinetic/
Autoware Version 1.11

The final results of the colcon build is.

```
Aborted  <<< lidar_euclidean_cluster_detect
Aborted  <<< costmap_generator
 
                                         
Summary: 121 packages finished [1min 18s]

    1 package failed: lidar_localizer
    7 packages aborted: costmap_generator lidar_euclidean_cluster_detect naive_motion_predict points_preprocessor road_occupancy_processor sick_ldmrs_laser trafficlight_recognizer
    3 packages had stderr output: lidar_euclidean_cluster_detect lidar_localizer trafficlight_recognizer
    10 packages not processed
```

One error occurred in the  code for ndt_mapping

```
[Processing: dp_planner, ff_waypoint_follower, lattice_planner, lidar_kf_contour_track, lidar_localizer, trafficlight_recognizer, way_planner, waypoint_maker]
--- stderr: lidar_localizer                                                    
    In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Eigenvalues:35:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:7,
                 from /home/joshua/autoware.ai/install/ndt_cpu/include/ndt_cpu/Registration.h:4,
                 from /home/joshua/autoware.ai/install/ndt_cpu/include/ndt_cpu/NormalDistributionsTransform.h:4,
                 from /home/joshua/autoware.ai/src/autoware/core_perception/lidar_localizer/nodes/ndt_matching/ndt_matching.cpp:56:
    /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/misc/RealSvd2x2.h:19:6: error: redefinition of ‘template<class MatrixType, class RealScalar, class Index> void Eigen::internal::real_2x2_jacobi_svd(const MatrixType&, Index, Index, Eigen::JacobiRotation<RealScalar>*, Eigen::JacobiRotation<RealScalar>*)’
 void real_2x2_jacobi_svd(const MatrixType& matrix, Index p, Index q,
      ^
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/SVD:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Geometry:15,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/point_cloud.h:47,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/pcl_ros/point_cloud.h:5,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/velodyne_pointcloud/rawdata.h:33,
                 from /home/joshua/autoware.ai/src/autoware/core_perception/lidar_localizer/nodes/ndt_matching/ndt_matching.cpp:41:
    /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SVD/JacobiSVD.h:405:6: note: ‘template<class MatrixType, class RealScalar, class Index> void Eigen::internal::real_2x2_jacobi_svd(const MatrixType&, Index, Index, Eigen::JacobiRotation<RealScalar>*, Eigen::JacobiRotation<RealScalar>*)’ previously declared here


 void real_2x2_jacobi_svd(const MatrixType& matrix, Index p, Index q,
      ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Eigenvalues:35:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense:7,
                 from /home/joshua/autoware.ai/install/ndt_cpu/include/ndt_cpu/Registration.h:4,
                 from /home/joshua/autoware.ai/install/ndt_cpu/include/ndt_cpu/NormalDistributionsTransform.h:4,
                 from /home/joshua/autoware.ai/src/autoware/core_perception/lidar_localizer/nodes/ndt_mapping/ndt_mapping.cpp:47:
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/misc/RealSvd2x2.h:19:6: error: redefinition of ‘template<class MatrixType, class RealScalar, class Index> void Eigen::internal::real_2x2_jacobi_svd(const MatrixType&, Index, Index, Eigen::JacobiRotation<RealScalar>*, Eigen::JacobiRotation<RealScalar>*)’
 void real_2x2_jacobi_svd(const MatrixType& matrix, Index p, Index q,
      ^
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/SVD:36:0,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Geometry:15,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/point_cloud.h:47,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/pcl_ros/point_cloud.h:5,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/velodyne_pointcloud/rawdata.h:33,
                 from /home/joshua/autoware.ai/src/autoware/core_perception/lidar_localizer/nodes/ndt_mapping/ndt_mapping.cpp:37:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SVD/JacobiSVD.h:405:6: note: ‘template<class MatrixType, class RealScalar, class Index> void Eigen::internal::real_2x2_jacobi_svd(const MatrixType&, Index, Index, Eigen::JacobiRotation<RealScalar>*, Eigen::JacobiRotation<RealScalar>*)’ previously declared here
 void real_2x2_jacobi_svd(const MatrixType& matrix, Index p, Index q,
      ^
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ndt_mapping.dir/nodes/ndt_mapping/ndt_mapping.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ndt_mapping.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ndt_matching.dir/nodes/ndt_matching/ndt_matching.cpp.o] Error 1   
   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ndt_matching.dir/all] Error 2
   make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I would like to know how to fix this. Please advise.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329076/how-to-fix-error-in-building-the-lidar_localizer-package?/) by [JoshuaSiy](https://answers.ros.org/users/44160/joshuasiy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2019-07-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that Eigen::internal::real_2x2_jacobi_svd funtion is defined twice.

Please reinstall Eigen.

As shown in the following commit, it seems to move the function from JacobiSVD.h to RealSvd2x2.h.
https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/commits/eb8d87ca2cfc24629a76942b445880a199a2d5e2

---

Originally posted by [Yamato Ando](https://answers.ros.org/users/43573/yamato-ando/) with karma: 231 on 2019-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JoshuaSiy](https://answers.ros.org/users/44160/joshuasiy/) on 2019-07-24**:
Thank you.

**Comment by [mhxu](https://answers.ros.org/users/45063/mhxu/) on 2019-08-22**:
Still having the problem after uninstall and reinstall Eigen. Should I switch to an older version of Eigen?

**Comment by [Yamato Ando](https://answers.ros.org/users/43573/yamato-ando/) on 2019-08-26**:
@mhxu Are you exactly the same error? Are two Eigen installed?
Either uninstall one or set it so that it will not be referenced during build.

**Comment by [mhxu](https://answers.ros.org/users/45063/mhxu/) on 2019-08-26**:
@Yamato Ando . Yes, I think the problem might be two Eigen were installed. I figured out that I don't have to manually install Eigen from source. Eigen has already been installed on my machine by command `apt-get install libeigen3-dev`.

**Comment by [Yamato Ando](https://answers.ros.org/users/43573/yamato-ando/) on 2019-08-27**:
@mhxu Could you remove Eigen installed from source?
Like the command,

```
$ cd <Eigen-source-directory>/build
$ sudo make uninstall
```

**Comment by [mhxu](https://answers.ros.org/users/45063/mhxu/) on 2019-08-27**:
@Yamato Ando . Problem resolved after removing the Eigen from source. Thank you.

**Comment by [Yamato Ando](https://answers.ros.org/users/43573/yamato-ando/) on 2019-08-27**:
@mhxu Great !

**Comment by [Eleonore](https://answers.ros.org/users/56050/eleonore/) on 2020-06-23**:
Hi, I have the same issue. However, i do not manage to uninstall eigen from source, there is no build folder. I tried sudo apt remove libeigen3-dev but then I have other issues. Could you be more specific on how you solved the problem. Thanks !